# To-Do List in React

Tags: javascript, react.js, to-do-list

I've written a to-do list app in React, as I am a beginner and this is my first app, I feel it can be improved. Some assistance in improving it, and how or why improvements are better would be much appreciated.

Here is a [working demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92838694/React/index.html) of it.

```
var ToDoContainer = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        var tasks = [
                {task:"Go to the gym", completed:false, id:1 }, 
                {task:"Do yoga", completed:false, id:2 },
                {task:"Buy groceries", completed:true, id:3 },
                {task:"Get tire fixed", completed:true, id:4}
        ];

        return {
            tasks:tasks,
            numCompleted:null
        }
    },
    addTask: function(task){
        this.setState({
            tasks:this.state.tasks.concat(task) 
        }); 
    },
    clearComplete: function(){

        var remainingTasks = this.state.tasks.filter(function(task){
            if (!task.completed) return task;
        });

        this.setState({
            tasks:remainingTasks
        });

    },
    markComplete: function(e){
        console.log('markComplete')
        var id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        var tempTasks = this.state.tasks;

        tempTasks.forEach(function(task){
            if (id == task.id) {
                if (task.completed){
                    task.completed = false; 
                }
                else if (!task.completed) {
                    task.completed = true;  
                }
            }
        })

        this.setState({
            tasks:tempTasks
        });
    },
    render: function(){
        var numCompleted = this.state.tasks.filter(function(task){
            return task.completed;
        }).length

        var numRemaining = this.state.tasks.filter(function(task){
            return !task.completed;
        }).length

        return (
            <div className="rowFluid">
                <div className="well row col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <h3 className="text-left">You have {numRemaining} tasks to do:</h3>
                    <TaskList tasks={this.state.tasks} check={this.markComplete} />
                    <AddTask addNew={this.addTask} />
                    <ClearTask clear={this.clearComplete} numCompleted={numCompleted}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var TaskList = React.createClass({
    handleCheck: function(e){
        console.log('handleCheck')
        this.props.check(e);
    },
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            data:this.props.tasks
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        var that = this;

        var task = this.props.tasks.map(function(task, index){
                return <li key={index} className={task.completed ? "complete" : "incomplete"} >
                            <input type="checkbox" checked={task.completed} onChange={that.handleCheck} data-id={task.id}/>
                            {task.task}
                        </li>
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                    {task}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var AddTask = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return{
            newTask:""
        }
    },
    handleChange: function(e){
        this.setState({
            newTask:e.target.value
        });
    },
    handleSubmit: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.addNew({task:this.state.newTask, completed:false, id:Date.now()});
        this.setState({
            newTask:""
        });
    },
    render: function(){
        var inputStyle = {
            marginRight: "10px"
        }

        return (    
            <div className="text-left">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.newTask} onChange={this.handleChange} style={inputStyle}/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Task" disabled={this.state.newTask == ""} />
                </form>
            </div>

        )
    }
});

var ClearTask = React.createClass({

    clear: function(){
        this.props.clear();
    },
    render: function(){
        var buttonStyle = {
            marginTop: "10px"
        }

        return (
            <button onClick={this.clear} value="Clear Completed" clear={this.clearComplete} disabled={this.props.numCompleted==0} className="text-center" style={buttonStyle}>Clear Completed</button>
        )   
    }
})


ReactDOM.render(<ToDoContainer />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return {
    tasks:tasks,
    numCompleted:null
}
```

`numCompleted` isn't being used anywhere. Remove if from the data. Also, it's a "computed property", one you can compute off from `tasks`. I notice you compute it on render. Consider putting it in a function instead.

```
getCompletedTaskCount: function(){
  return this.state.tasks.filter(task => task.completed).length;
},
getNotCompletedTaskCount: function(){
  return this.state.tasks.filter(task => !task.completed).length;
},
clearComplete: function(){
    this.setState({
        tasks: this.state.tasks.filter(task => !task.completed);
    });
},
```

Since you're using React, I assume you use Babel, and thus we have access to ES6 transpilation. ES6 provides new syntax to simplify your code. In the example above, I use arrow functions and their ability to implicitly return the expression value.

Also, I notice that you count the complete and incomplete tasks on render. I suggest you move these logic into functions so that they can be reused. It also makes them visible, and reduces clutter in the `render` function.

```
markComplete: function(e){
    console.log('markComplete')
    var id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    var tempTasks = this.state.tasks;

    tempTasks.forEach(function(task){
        if (id == task.id) {
            if (task.completed){
                task.completed = false; 
            }
            else if (!task.completed) {
                task.completed = true;  
            }
        }
    })

    this.setState({
        tasks:tempTasks
    });
},
```

I suggest against `console.log` for debugging. The last thing you'd ever want to make a habit of is forgetting `console` calls in your code. I suggest you learn using breakpoints in dev tools. Much more powerful and doesn't leave trash in the code.

`markComplete` is misleading. It's not really just marking the tasks complete. It's *toggling* the complete state. You should name it appropriately, like `toggleCompleteness`.

```
return <li key={index} className={task.completed ? "complete" : "incomplete"} >
```

The problem here is your CSS classes. `complete` and `incomplete` are very generic. It could possibly be killed by other libraries in your app that use those very same names. With that, you'd start to think about namespacing, and your CSS tends to end up like:

```
.todo-list .task .complete{...}
```

The effect is that this style has a specificity of `0-3-0` (0 ids, 3 classes, 0 elements). To override it, you'll need `1-x-x` (an id) or `0-4-0` (4 classes) or a `0-3-0` (3 classes, but defined after). This becomes a headache as the app grows larger, and make your CSS life a battle of overrides.

To counter this problem, I suggest you read about [`BEM`](http://getbem.com/introduction/). In a gist, it's a naming convention for CSS classes that allow you to build low-specificity, precisely targeted selectors that are easily identifiable. You don't even need to override if you can safely say this style only affects this component and nothing else.

```
this.props.addNew({task:this.state.newTask, completed:false, id:Date.now()});
```

The `completed` and `id` should be filled in by the `addTask` in the very top-most component, and that `addNew` should only be called with `newTask`. This is to isolate the knowledge of the data structure to just one location in the code.

A relevant scenario would be when your data structure changes. If you wrote it this way, you'd be hunting for hard-coded data structures. Whereas if you just isolated it in one place, you'd only change that portion of the code.

Also, don't use `Date.now()` as an ID. Generate GUIDs instead. [Here's an handy implementation in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/105074/575527). If you're just after a quick way to identify things, I personally use `('' + Math.random()).slice(2)` for a quick ID solution as `Date.now()` can yield the same value if you run it in rapid succession (like in loops).

```
<div className="text-left">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.newTask} onChange={this.handleChange} style={inputStyle}/>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Task" disabled={this.state.newTask == ""} />
    </form>
</div>
```

A `<form>` is overkill here, as your handler doesn't use anything about the form aside from hooking to the `onSubmit` event. You can remove the `<form>`, replace the input button input with a `<button>` and put an `onClick` on it that calls `handleSubmit`.

```
var buttonStyle = {
    marginTop: "10px"
}
```

Another reason to use BEM convention is that inline styles are higher in specificity than IDs, and the only way to override them is to replace the inline style or use `!important` in a stylesheet. Again, you don't want your CSS to be a battle of overrides.

Comment: This was very thorough.  Thank-you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 3):

I can't offer a full review for you right now, but here are a couple little things:

### A couple simplifications

In `ToDoContainer.render`, this:

```
var numCompleted = this.state.tasks.filter(function(task){
    return task.completed;
}).length

var numRemaining = this.state.tasks.filter(function(task){
    return !task.completed;
}).length
```

is doing extra work. `numRemaining` is just `this.state.tasks.length - numCompleted`, no need to do a second `filter`.

Also, in `ToDoContainer.clearComplete`, this:

```
var remainingTasks = this.state.tasks.filter(function(task){
    if (!task.completed) return task;
});
```

can be simplified slightly into

```
var remainingTasks = this.state.tasks.filter(function(task) {
    return !task.completed;
});
```

because `filter` only cares about the true/false-y result of your function.

#### Toggling a boolean

In `ToDoContainer.markComplete`, this:

```
if (task.completed){
    task.completed = false; 
}
else if (!task.completed) {
    task.completed = true;  
}
```

can be simplified into

```
task.completed = !task.completed;
```

which is a common idiom for toggling a boolean.

Comment: This will help to make my code more concise.  Thank-you.